# extract characters from second occurrence of dash in a string

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a string "*apple-rose-orange-21-X-84*"; I need to extract the string after the second occurrence of "*-*" using shell script.

The answer should be **orange-21-X-84**.

How would I do this in shell script, I have tried several ways, couldn't find an answer.

Comment: `s='apple-rose-orange-21-X-84'; t=${s#*-}; answer=${t#*-}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please show the several ways you tried.

Answer (score 4):

shell only solution:

```
string='apple-rose-orange-21-X-84'
echo ${string#*-*-}
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> **${parameter#word}**
>
> **${parameter##word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a
>   pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see
>   Pattern Matching). If the pattern matches the beginning of the
>   expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the
>   expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the
>   ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If
>   parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to
>   each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’,
>   the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array
>   in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: This should work for any POSIX shell, not just bash.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` command:

```sh
$ cut -d- -f3- <<<'apple-rose-orange-21-X-84'
orange-21-X-84
```

`-d-` sets the dash as cut's delimiter. `-f3-` selects from the 3rd to last field. `<<<` makes a here-string. For a more detailed explanation see `man cut` and `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few *POSIX* shell methods, (no `bash` or external utils needed):

1. Using pipes and `read`:

   ```
   echo apple-rose-orange-21-X-84 | (IFS="-" read a b c; echo $c;)
   ```
2. Using parameter substitution:

   ```
   s=apple-rose-orange-21-X-84; echo ${s#*-*-}
   ```